# memset identifier not found

Tags: c++, mex

I am writing a mex function using cpp compiler. My problem is whenever I use this line:

```
memset(*(new_gammas+i), 0, llrlength*sizeof(double));
```

I am getting from compiler:
**`"memset" identifier not found.`**
Is it because of the lack of any specific header file or the code is wrong for c++?

Comment: Please provide a complete example which illustrates what you are trying to do. Give enough code so that anyone can copy and paste it and compile it for themselves and get the same error.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset. For header and example of use.

Answer (score 2):

memset is declared in `<cstring>` and is in the `std` namespace.